# Derivative of a function over itself

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm new in calculus and I have such a problem. I cannot understand what is the derivative of a real-valued function over itself. Something like that: $$f=f(x), x\in\mathbb R$$$$f'(f)=?$$

Finally I figured out what I'm talking about. It's a variational derivative http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FunctionalDerivative.html

Comment: i would start this with an example

Comment: Look up chain rule.

Comment: Regarding the additional comment you made in a 2-days later edit, the variational derivative is not something a person "new in calculus" would be in a position to understand.

Comment: But it does not seems to be much more complicated than "usual" derivative

Answer (score 0):

If you mean $$(f(f(x)))'$$ then it's
$$f'(f(x))f'(x).$$

Answer (score 0):

$f(f)$ does not make sense. A function $f: A \rightarrow B$ maps elements in $A$ to elements in $B$. For example, the function $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ defined as $f(x) = x^2$ maps an integer $x$ to another integer $x^2$. Using this same case, it's clear to see $f(f)$ would not make sense, as $f$ is a function, not an integer, so $f(f)$ is essentially taking in a function as its input, which violates the definition of $f$ mapping integers to integers.

As stated already, $f(f(x))$ makes sense, as $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $f$ can take in $f(x)$ as an input. Recall for a function $g$, $(g(u))' = g'(u)u'$. So, $(f(f(x)))' = f'(f(x))f'(x)$